# Beta-t-EGARCH model, what is the unconditional variance

Tags: r, variance, garch

I am trying to implement Beta-t-EGARCH model in R, however, I fail to understand what is the unconditional variance of this model. I know for simple GARCH model, unconditional variance is

```
ARCH0/ (1-ARCH1 - Beta1),
```

but what I have read for Beta-t-EGARCH model the unconditional variance is equal to $\frac{\omega}{1-\phi_1}$. So in my case it would be:

```
Coefficients:
                  omega         phi1      kappa1   kappastar        df       
  Estimate:  -2.9495492 0.9990466008 0.040487373 0.007719683 8.5488304

-2.84/(1-0.99904) = uncond. variance
```

and as you can see it does not make sense.

If anyone knows how to calculate unconditional variance, please help. Here is a link to a pdf with the [model and R code](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2013-2/sucarrat.pdf)

Comment: It is always a good idea to give a formula for the model you are asking a question, so the question is self-contained. As for unconditional variance, as far as I know, all the volatility models are accompanied by the formula for unconditional variance. So you just need to find the correct formula. As @tchakravarty suggested the answer is probably $\frac{\exp(\omega)}{1-\phi_1}$. However looking at the model it is not immediately evident that this is the case, because the definition of this model is really complicated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to exponentiate the expression. Recall that an EGARCH model is $\mathbf{\log} \sigma_t^2 = \omega + \alpha_1 \sigma_{t-1}^2 + \beta_1 Y_t^2$.

Answer (score 1):

This question is somewhat related to this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/313283/expression-for-the-unconditional-variance-in-the-egarch-model?rq=1). In a model specified in the logarithm of variance, we cannot just exponentiate the unconditional log variance to obtain the unconditional variance. This is due to Jensen's inequality, i.e. $\text{E} \left[ \log \sigma_t^2 \right] \neq  \log \left(\text{E} \left[ \sigma_t^2 \right] \right)$.

Thus, it is unlikely that we have a closed form expression available.

Answer (score 0):

Struggling with this myself.  As conditional variance is derived from λ as in following formula σt=exp(λt/2) and  δ/(1-φ) is mean of λ, unconditional variance of time series should be (exp((δ/(1-φ)/2))^2.  Please comment if this is correct. Thank you.