# Expression for the unconditional variance in the EGARCH model

Tags: time-series, econometrics, garch, volatility-forecasting

Given the EGARCH specification:

$\log(\sigma_t^2)=\omega + \alpha(|z_{t-1}| + E[|z_{t-1}|]) + \gamma z_{t-1} + \beta \log(\sigma_{t-1}^2)$

Is it possible to find a closed-form solution for the unconditional variance?

Some sources such as [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/econ/assess-egarch-forecast-bias-through-simulations.html) propose $e^{\frac{\omega}{1 - \beta}}$, but Matlab does not state its source and I cannot find anything elsewhere. Is there an academic source or a proof that shows that $e^{\frac{\omega}{1 - \beta}}$ is the long term variance for an EGARCH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The moment structure of the first-order Exponential GARCH model is derived by He, Teräsvirta and Malmsten in "Moment Structure of a Family of First-Order Exponential GARCH Models".

The matlab reference presents the "the exponentiated, theoretical unconditional log variance", which is not identical to the unconditional variance.

The unconditional second moment is:

\begin{equation} 
\sigma^2 = \nu_2 \exp \{2\omega(1-\beta)^{-1}\} \prod_{i=1}^{\infty} E\left[ \exp\{2\beta^{i-1}g(z_t)\}\right],\end{equation}
where $g(z_t) = \gamma z_t + \alpha(\vert z_t \vert - E\vert z_t \vert)$ and $\nu_2 = E\vert z_t\vert^2$.

Comment: Could you edit this to directly answer the OP original question about whether the closed form solution s/he found is indeed the correct one?

Comment: I have tried to update the answer to include the requested details.

Comment: Is it $E|z_t|^2 = (E|z_t|)^2$ or $E|z_t|^2 = E(|z_t|^2)$?

Comment: It is $E \left( \vert z_t \vert^2 \right)$ as far as I can see in the paper.